# What is the purpose of the MathContext parameter in the methods of BigDecimal class?

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal, mathcontext

The [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class has the following arithmetic and rounding methods:

```
BigDecimal add     (BigDecimal y)
BigDecimal subtract(BigDecimal y)
BigDecimal multiply(BigDecimal y)
BigDecimal divide  (BigDecimal y, [int scale,] RoundingMode rm)
BigDecimal setScale(int scale, RoundingMode rm)
```

The `divide` and `setScale` methods have the *scale* parameter, which defines the number of digits **after the decimal point** in the method result. We can use this parameter to round a number, for example, to 2 decimal places in order to display it to a user or store them in a database.

Java 5 introduced the following new methods to the BigDecimal class:

```
BigDecimal add     (BigDecimal y, MathContext mc)
BigDecimal subtract(BigDecimal y, MathContext mc)
BigDecimal multiply(BigDecimal y, MathContext mc)
BigDecimal divide  (BigDecimal y, MathContext mc)
BigDecimal round   (MathContext mc)
```

The *[MathContext](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/math/MathContext.html) mc* parameter defines the precision of a method result, that is the **total number of digits in it, i.e. both before and after the decimal point**.
But what is the purpose of the *mc* parameter? I don't think it is, for example, for rounding a number to 7 digits in order to display it to a user, because what's the point of rounding to 7 digits if the rounded numbers have a different number of digits after the decimal point? Maybe it is for defining the precision of intermediate results, e.g. resulting from the division 1/3 = 0.3333333333333333?

Unfortunately, the purpose of MathContext parameters isn't described in API documentation.
I have no code to show, I am only learning Java and wonder about the meaning of this parameter.

Comment: BigDecimal, by definition, is unbounded. So if you want to do, say, 16 bit, or 32 bit or even 128 bits maths while your numbers are BigDecimal, you're going to _need_ a MathContext.